# Broadcast Receivers - can you miss some broadcasts if registering/unregistering on onResume/onPause?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

If you register and unregister broadcast receivers on the methods onPause and onResume on every activity,
is there a chance to miss some of the broadcasts when you switch between activities? There is some time between those two methods, and if in that point a broadcast is triggered, will the app skip it?

Thanks for the information,
Dan

Comment: yes, those broadcast will not catched ... you can put them to Service, start Service in first Activity and then bind it in every Activity then you should be able to catch every broadcast ... or you can live with this (depends on tour needs)

Answer (score 0):

there will be a brief moment where they will not be catches.
i would propose to delay the unregister for a sec by using postDelayed in the Handler class
but that way it might be captured on both at the same time .
i cant propose a solution unless you have a scenario .
for example in my application it is not essential to handle this case because every activity has its own use of the Broadcasts and thus i don't care about this case.